# Is it possible to run Java applets in IE when running under wine?

Tags: internet-explorer, wine, java-applet

Where I work we develop a web based application that happens to use applets, however most of us do not run Windows, and so it is not easy to test internet explorer "natively". Setting up internet explorer to run under wine is pretty easy, however I have been having much greater problems getting java applets to run under wine.

Is there a way to do this, easy or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> test internet explorer "natively".

I wouldn't rely on wine to give you a native IE java applet experience. Maybe Windows on VirtualBox, but bottom line is that only Windows can give you that native experience. Not trying to be rude, but I think testing should be done on the specific software it is designed for. Perhaps a simple dual boot?

Comment: To be honest, I don't care about a "native" java applet experience, close enough is good enough. Final testing will always need to be done on a real windows box, but for development testing you need an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

See [Running Java Applets in Internet Explorer on Linux](http://rmathew.blogspot.com/2007/04/running-java-applets-in-internet.html).